# session variables in an ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, session-variables

hi guy i am trying to place my session in to a drop down, any help would be great.
at the moment it puts the data in to a label, i wish to put it into a dropdown with it adding a new string every time i click button without getting rid of the last

default page

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Fruitname"] = TbxName.Text; // my session i have made
}
```

output page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var  fruitname =  Session["Fruitname"] as String; // my session ive made
    fruit.Text = fruitname; // session used in lable
}
```

Have Tried

```
           var myFruits = Session["Fruitname"] as List<string>;
        myFruits.Add(listbox1.Text);
```

but i get error when i try to run the program

Broken glass thanks for your help, it is still not doing what i need but its getting there.

```
 var fruitname = Session["Fruitname"] as String; // my session ive made
           fruit.Text = string.Join(",", fruitname); // session used in lable
```

this is what is working. i need a dropdown to display all the strings put into  TbxName.Text; to output into fruit

Comment: you can't convert a list of strings to a string - you can either decide to display all of them e.g. `fruit.Text = string.Join(",", myFruits)` or just one of them e.g. `fruit.Text = myFruits.First()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a `List<string>` instead of a string then.

```
 var myFruits = Session["Fruitname"] as List<string>;
 myFruits.Add(TbxName.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you almost there but still not running due to TbxName not being declared in the output page, any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Has been fixed using code found else where

**button page code bellow**

```
 protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       // Session["Fruitname"] = TbxName.Text; // my session i have made

        MyFruit = Session["Fruitname"] as List<string>;
        //Create new, if null
        if (MyFruit == null)
            MyFruit = new List<string>();

        MyFruit.Add(TbxName.Text);

        Session["Fruitname"] = MyFruit;
{
public List<string> MyFruit { get; set; }
}
```

**page where display**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        MyFruit = Session["Fruitname"] as List<string>;
        //Create new, if null
        if (MyFruit == null)
            MyFruit = new List<string>();
        ListBox1.DataSource = MyFruit;
        ListBox1.DataBind();


    }

    public List<string> MyFruit { get; set; }
}
```